# Micronaut cli graphql setup

Tags: java, kotlin, command-line-interface, graphql, micronaut

Is it possible to pass a feature to micronaut cli to integrate a new application with graphQL, for example like this:

```
mn create-app -f grephql name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no. The current GraphQL support does not have a corresponding feature in the CLI. https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-graphql